# Dynamic delete statement based on join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure with a GroupUserTVP table-valued parameter:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[GroupUserTVP] AS TABLE
(
    [GroupId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
)
```

I have a `GroupUser` table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GroupUser]
(
    [GroupId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
)
```

The TVP will contain a collection of GroupId's and UserId's.  If the GroupUser table has group-users which don't exist in the TVP then those group-users should be deleted.

Is there a way to do some type of dynamic delete statement based on a join to accomplish this? I can break this into pieces and use table variables, etc but was wondering if there's a SQL expert here who could write this delete in a single statement or maybe 2 statements?

Comment: You said "If the GroupUser table has group-users which don't exist in the TVP then those group-users should be deleted." You *may* need to be more specific, if you are referring to one of the two columns, or both.

Comment: I'm referring to a distinct group-user combination.  so if {groupid=1,userid=2} exists in the table but not in the tvp then it should be deleted

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE tvp
FROM TVP tvp
FULL OUTER JOIN SimpleTable tbl
ON tvp.FK = tbl.ID`

It will delete all records that don't exist in your Simple table

Comment: I think that you want to delete tvp instead of w

Comment: `OUTER`, not `OUTTER`. Also, when using an answer, indent your code 4 (extra) whitespaces, or highlight it and click the `{}` button. It'll put it in the format like the OP has in their question. It makes it much easier to read. :)